# Probability of a disintegration

Tags: probability, translation-request

The half-life of Uranium-$238$ is $5×10^9$ years. What is the probability than a uranium atom disintegrates in any one year?

I think I have to use Poisson's law but I don't know how to apply it in this context.

Thank you in advance for any hints!

Comment: No need for Poisson's law. If it helps conceptually, try calculating how many atoms out of 10 million disintegrate in one year. The probability of a single atom disintegrating is then just gotten by dividing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [decay rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) $\lambda$ is closely related to half-life, 
$$ \lambda = \frac{\ln (2)}{t_{1/2}} $$

This gives the value you are looking for directly, 
$$\frac{\ln (2)}{5\cdot 10^9} = 1.39\cdot 10^{-10}$$

This is the instantaneous rate of change in the amount of uranium. The total amount of uranium is reducing at a rate of $1.39\cdot 10^{-10}$ per year. Therefore - since the change in this number is negligible over the course of a year, with such a long half-life - this is the probability associated with each atom in the uranium that it will decay over that year.

At the end of the year, the probabilities will have played out for each one of the atoms, and there will be $(1-1.39\cdot 10^{-10})$ times the initial amount of uranium left at the end of the year.

Comment: I don’t understand why $\lambda$ is the probability ...

Comment: @Shadock Updated answer to explain more fully

Comment: So if we wait 5 billion years then the probability is ln(2)? For me $P(t_{1/2})=1/2$ sorry but I think I don’t understand some shades ^^

Comment: If we take the time period as 5 billion years, the probability is 0.5, of course. As I said, considering one year, you can simply say the number of atoms is approximately unchanged from start to end, but over millions of years you have to adjust for the changing number of atoms. You don't simply add up the loss every year. This is perhaps clearer for more radioactive (shorter half-life) substances. The article on exponential decay I linked to is pretty clear. See how the slope changes over time.

Comment: I put an other demonstration here, it is very very simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Well after more thinking there is a "best" demonstration, because of the geometric law is without memory we search the probability $p$ for which :

$$
(1-p)^{5 \cdot 10^9}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

After calculs we have :

$$
p=\frac{\ln(2)}{5 \cdot 10^9} \approx 1.4 \cdot 10^{-10}
$$

Shadock ! :D

Comment: It is of course "very very simple" to state the answer (which I had already given you), but you don't really explain how you got there.